# Sum of reciprocals of partition numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {p(n)}$$ converge or diverge? and is there a proof of this?

p(n) is the [partition function](http://oeis.org/A000041).

Comment: It converges, alright. As for the proof, it's right [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pudding).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas), the partition function has the asymptotic approximation as $x\to\infty$: $$p(n)\sim \frac{1}{4n\sqrt3}\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2n}{3}}\right)$$ So yes, it converges very fast.

Comment: Even in the very limited case of the number of representations by a sum of three numbers, it is at least ${n-1\choose 2}\frac{1}{3!}$. You can show it by dividing $n$ balls in three parts and then restricting permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_3(n)$ denote the number of ways you can represent $n$ as the sum of $3$ non-negative integers.
Elementary combinatorics (see [[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html)],[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)]) gives $p_3(n)=\binom{n+2}{2}$.
Since $p(n)\geq p_3 (n)$ we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p(n)}$ converges by the direct comparison test.